# Is there a method to verify whether you have the correct solution for greatest/least values of arg z?

Tags: complex-numbers

I often solve questions that are about finding the greatest or least arg z values for points lying in a region and I was just wondering whether there is a way to verify or double-check if you've come up with the right solution or not (either during an exam or for practice purposes)?

For example, I had this particular question on one practice paper:

> On an Argand diagram, sketch the locus of points representing complex numbers **u** satisfying
> the relation |z-u| = 1, where **u** is -1+ 4√3i. Determine the greatest value of arg **z** for points on this locus.

I know the center is (-1, 4√3) and the radius is 1 and I can use the tan formula to get arctan (1/4√3) and then multiply the answer by 2 and add pi/2 to get the final answer that is = 1.86 radians, but is there any way I could verify whether my final answer is correct or incorrect during the exam?

Are there any methods that can help with minimizing errors as much as possible?
I do practice questions a lot but I honestly would like to know if there is any way I could make sure I do not make mistakes during an actual exam?

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: The expression $|z - u| = 1$ denotes the complex numbers which distance $1$ from $u$. Can you figure out what is this locus?

Comment: it is a circle with radius 1